# DAX method to replace COUNTIF for a row

Tags: rows, dax, countif

I am trying to use DAX to count the number of Fails (FailCount) per row for a PowerBI report. I could do this with COUNTIF in Excel.
Each row contains an item number, and the following columns contain the result (Pass/Fail/Null) from several tests.
This sample shows 3 tests, but there are 14 tests total in reality.

```
Item | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | FailCount

101  | Pass  | null  | Fail  | 1

102  | null  | Fail  | Fail  | 2

103  | Fail  | Pass  | null  | 1
```

All my searches have only turned up methods to count in a single column.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are adding the FailCount as a new calculated column.

You should be able to make a simple addition of all the Test columns like this:

```
FailCount:=
IF([Test1]="Fail",1) + IF([Test2]="Fail",1) + ... + IF([Test14]="Fail",1)
```

This will give you +1 in the FailCount column for each Test column with the value "Fail".

Test columns that contain other values than "Fail" will be counted as 0, because

```
IF("NotFail"="Fail",1)
```

will return BLANK, which is counted as 0 when added up.

Answer (score 0):

This solution finally worked for me

```
FailCount = (
0 
+
CALCULATE(COUNTA('Table1'[Test1]), 'Table1'[Test1] IN { "Fail" })
+
CALCULATE(COUNTA('Table1'[Test1]), 'Table1'[Test2] IN { "Fail" })
+
CALCULATE(COUNTA('Table1'[Test1]), 'Table1'[Test3] IN { "Fail" })
)
```